# Angular 5 @Input width and apply to div

Tags: html, angular, input

This has to be easy.  Trying to input a string like 50%, 50px, 20rem ... as a width and then apply it to the html for the component.

```
<test title="frump" width="50%"></test>

export class test {
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() width: string;
       ...
  getWidth() {
    return this.width;
  }

<div [ngStyle]="{'width.px': 'getWidth()', ... or
<div [ngStyle]="{'width': 'width', ...
```

The width is being totally ignored...  ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<div [ngStyle]="{'width': width, ...` or `<div [style.width]="width"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your problem is the quotations around 'width' (the second one). It's a variable so should not be in quotes. My example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tgqahd?file=app%2Fapp.component.html